# why Java only creating file without writing any data to it

Tags: java, swing, jtable, printwriter

I am trying to PrintWrite data to file but java create file only without writing any data.

Data is stored in an ArrayList and I think the issue because of the sData.size() method. The action method part is used when user click over save icon and table will not have any data. The user clicks the button to add data to Jtable.

The part of code at the end gives the error message `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

```
    public class ee extends JFrame {
            String[] columnNames = {"#", "c1", "c2", "data column"};

            public final JTable table;
            JToolBar toolBar;
            private final JTextField enterText,startTime,endTime;


            static DefaultTableModel cModel ;
            JButton Obutton;
            int  counter = 1;
          public static ArrayList<String> sData = new ArrayList<String>();
   public static ArrayList<String> eData = new ArrayList<String>();
   public static ArrayList<String> tData = new ArrayList<String>();

                 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
               {
                   ee is = new ee("iss");

               }


            //the constrictor 
            public ee(String title){
            cModel =new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);       
            table = new JTable(cModel);
```

action method

```
Action saveAction = new AbstractAction("Save", saveIcon) {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    File myFile = new File("the-file-name.txt");
                    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(myFile)) {   

                    for (int i =0 ; i< sData.size(); i++)
                    {

                    writer.println(i+1 + "\n");
                    writer.println(sData.get(i)+" --> " + eData.get(i));
                    writer.println(tData.get(i)+"\n");

                    }
                    }catch(FileNotFoundException ioEx){

                    } 

                }
            };  
        }
```

taking data from JTable and save it to ArrayList

```
public static ArrayList<String> getTableSTimeData(){

     sData = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i=0; i < cModel.getRowCount(); i++){      
               Object val = cModel.getValueAt(i, 1); // value of ith row and 3rd column
               sData.add((String) val);

            }

    return sData;
}
```

the way of data insert into JTable

```
public class MenuBarMethod implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
        Object buttonPressed=a.getSource();

       if(buttonPressed.equals(Obutton)){
           String STime = startTime.getText();
           String ETime = endTime.getText();
           String text = enterText.getText();
           clearEntity();
           cModel.addRow(new Object[] {getCounter(),STime, ETime, text});

       }
       }
    }


}
```

Comment: `getTableSTimeData()` method is never called hence `sData` is `null`.

Comment: Look at comment and code `Object val = cModel.getValueAt(i, 1); // value of ith row and 3rd column`

Comment: Please post complete code so that we can run it to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `ArrayList` at the time of declaration to avoid `NullPointerException`

```
public class ee extends JFrame {

   ...
   public static List<String> sData = new ArrayList<String>();
   public static List<String> eData = new ArrayList<String>();
   public static List<String> tData = new ArrayList<String>();
   ...
}
```

Comment: that is right i tried this but still it is not printing

Comment: the comment are not important it is right i forget to remove it

Comment: but now you are not getting `NullPointerException`. Right?

Comment: yes but i can't post the same question again don't worry you are going to get up vote and accept answer just try with me because the title is about print write

Comment: it is wrong when i add item to array it add it two times

Comment: sorry I was busy. Let me try to run to understand your code. I am here just for help not for any vote. :)

Comment: i edite the code with two initialization for sData and the error message i get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: OK I will tell once copied.